# Python Tkinter checkbox value not changing

Tags: python, ubuntu, tkinter

I'm sure I'm doing something ridiculous, but I can't seem to figure out what it is. I've never programmed in Python before.

Anyway, I have a variable for my checkbox value, but the value of it doesn't change when clicking on the checkb. It always prints out 0. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Running on Ubuntu 13.10 Python 2.7

program.py

```
from Tkinter import *

class Program:
    def __init__(self):
        top = Tk()

        self.chk1Checked = BooleanVar()

        chk1 = Checkbutton(top, text = "Testing", variable = self.chk1Checked)
        chk1.pack()

        btn1 = Button(top, text = "Click Me", command = self.btn1CallBack)
        btn1.pack()

        top.mainloop()

    def btn1CallBack(self):
        print self.chk1Checked.get()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    Program()
```

Comment: Running your code works perfectly for me.

Comment: It works for me also, it prints out `True` when the box is checked and `False` when it is not.

Comment: Hmm, I wonder if it's a problem specific to Ubuntu or Linux, what OS are you guys using?

Answer (score 0):

It is a problem with my editor(IEP). When running from the command line everything works fine.

I was able to get it to work in IEP after changing my startup script to the program.py file. instead of just running the file itself. Not sure why this fixes it.